# How to distinct counting with Spring JPA Repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

How do I do a distinct counting with Spring Data JPA? I do not want to use the `@Query` annotation. The equivalent sql query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rack) FROM store WHERE id = 10001;
```

I tried by writing the following query, but it isn't working:

```
int countDistinctRackById();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work :

```
Integer countDistinctRackById(Long id);
```

Comment: I've just tested that approach ant it did't work (Spring Boot 2.2.2). Please provide more info

Comment: can you provide more info? entity class, repository method etc?

Comment: Sure. My repo extends from `JpaRepository`, entity class has field `customerId` and field `decision` and I need to fetch distinct count of customers for which `decision` code is one of needed values. I gave to method name `countDistinctCustomerIdByDecisionIn`, but generated SQL was not `select count(distinct CUSTOMER_ID) ...` but `select distinct count(distinct ID) ...`

Comment: not sure if that helps, but this looks like an issue with the `In` keyword. again I need more info to help (method's return type, entity's field type, etc)

Comment: This method does not actually produce a distinct count of the chosen field. it returns a distinct count of the Primary keys and completely ignores the field name portion.

Answer (score 5):

Try this according to [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation):

```
Integer countDistinctRackById(String id);
```

Replace the word `Rack` with the actual name of rack field

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this out and none of the existing answers work.

The following query:

`Integer countDistinctRackById(String id);`

Will render something like this:

`select distinct count(table0_.rack) as col_0_0_ from table table0_ where table0_.id=?`

As I am currently stuck with Spring Boot 1.2.3, idk if there were any changes later, but to achieve a count distinct I had to define a custom query:

`@Query("Select count(distinct rack) from Table t where t.id = ?1")`

Answer (score 0):

Update 2024: [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) has a warning section for DISTINCT (Spring Data JPA 3.2.4):

> DISTINCT can be tricky and not always producing the results you expect. For example, select distinct u from User u will produce a complete different result than select distinct u.lastname from User u. In the first case, since you are including User.id, nothing will duplicated, hence you’ll get the whole table, and it would be of User objects.

> However, that latter query would narrow the focus to just User.lastname and find all unique last names for that table. This would also yield a List result set instead of a List result set.
>
> countDistinctByLastname(String lastname) can also produce unexpected results. Spring Data JPA will derive select count(distinct u.id) from User u where u.lastname = ?1. Again, since u.id won’t hit any duplicates, this query will count up all the users that had the binding last name. Which would the same as countByLastname(String lastname)!

...

> Using distinct sometimes requires writing the query by hand and using @Query to best capture the information you seek, since you also may be needing a projection to capture the result set.

So it's best to check the generated query, or write the query yourself.